# Dynamic content view using fancybox

Tags: jquery, popup, fancybox, modal-dialog

I need to view the dynamic content in fancybox

my code looks like

```
<a id="featureExpertPopup" href="#featureExpertPop">View Profile </a>
<a id="featureExpertPopup" href="#featureExpertPop">View Profile </a>
<a id="featureExpertPopup" href="#featureExpertPop">View Profile </a>
```

and fancy box content

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <div id="featureExpertPop" style="overflow:auto;">Dynamic Profile</div>
</div>
```

fancybox call

```
$("#featureExpertPopup").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none'

    });
```

Now the problem is popup opening for first anchor link only, i want to open popup for each link with different content (from database)based on profile id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not use one `ID` for multiple elements, use `class` instead:

```
<a class="featureExpertPopup" id='one' href="#featureExpertPop">View Profile </a>
<a class="featureExpertPopup" id='two' href="#featureExpertPop">View Profile </a>
<a class="featureExpertPopup" id='three 'href="#featureExpertPop">View Profile </a>\

$(".featureExpertPopup").fancybox({ ... })
```

---

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href') + $(this).attr('id');
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for immediate response. Its working fine. Now i want send the id to generate dynamic content-`<a class="featureExpertPopup" href="#featureExpertPop?1d=1">View Profile </a>`

Comment: can we get the id using php get method or some other way? i need to pass the id with `href` like `href="profile.php?id=1"`

Comment: @LearneR unfortunately no, try the updated answer, you can also modify the `href` attribute manually.

Comment: Finally i got it, I made a separate file for popup content and passed the id as query string. Working fine. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use same ID for different elements. Use class instead of ID

```
<a class="featureExpertPopup" href="#featureExpertPop">View Profile </a>
<a class="featureExpertPopup" href="#featureExpertPop">View Profile </a>
<a class="featureExpertPopup" href="#featureExpertPop">View Profile </a>


$(".featureExpertPopup").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none'

    });
```

Comment: Thanks Miqdad Ali, I fixed it.